# How to get command line :g to output pattern search result including the first line?

Tags: regular-expression

When I use the normal mode and output the search result using the following input,

```
/LOAD \d\{-}\_p\+\d\n
```

it includes the first line,
[image]

However when I use the ex-command,

```
:g/LOAD \d\{-}\_p\+\d\n/z
```

The output does not show the first line (line #504 is missing).

[image]

My intention is to redirect the output of the ex-command to another file, using the :redir command. How to include the first line to the search output using the ex-command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not caused by the `:g` command or the matching, but by the `:z` command. If you go to the `LOAD` line and do `:z`, the same thing happens.

Strange workaround: Do `:g/pattern/-0z`

Answer (score 1):

What about `:% g/\vLOAD\_p+/`, this uses "magic" and makes the regex more readable. You can read about it in more detail in [`:h /magic`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'magic')

This also solves the disappearing first line.